# Checking if a word exists in a file

Tags: python, file, python-3.x

I am trying to make a program that takes a file which contains a list of words and user must enter a word that exists in the file. Can you tell me where is the wrong?

```
file = open('filename')
word_list = file.readlines()
print(word_list)
while True:
    word = input('type in word, must be in English and at least 3 letters long: ')
    if word in word_list:
        break;
    else:
        print("Try Again")
```

Comment: You should tell _us_ what's wrong by providing sample input and output. In any case, `word_list` contains each _line_ in the file, not each _word_.

Comment: Hint: why does `"c" in ["a b", "c d"]` evaluate to False? Why does `"b" in ["a\n", "b\n", "c"]` evaluate to False?

Comment: `word_list = file.read().split()`?

Comment: Every line in file is a word... So the inputed word is a line...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
file = open('filename', 'r')
word_list = []
for line in file:
    line = line.strip()
    list = line.split()
    word_list.extend(list)

word_list = list(set(word_list))  # Make list with unique values.
while True:
    word = input('type in word, must be in English and at least 3 letters long: ')
    if word in word_list:
        break
    else:
        print("Try Again")
file.close()
```

Comment: > Can you tell me where is the wrong?

Comment: @vaultah, the problem is that in the posted code, the file.readlines() results in a list of strings that are terminated in '\n'. As @Kevin hinted above, this causes your comparisons to fail because `'a' in ['a\n', 'b\n']` will evaluate to false.

Comment: @JCVanHamme: yes. Kamejoin decided to not include the explanation in their answer.

Comment: Actually.. When i run it with a small file i can execute it... But when i run it with a large text file (with many many words) i cant execute it... Any thoughts?